# Node Webkit program crashes with nwdirectory

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-webkit

I'm trying to create a directory selection dialog in my node webkit program.

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/File-dialogs) I just have to add nwdirectory to my file dialog.

Every time I use the file dialog, after selecting a folder and clicking ok, my program will hang for a few seconds, and then exit without any error messages.

I've attempted to use the webkit flag webkitdirectory, as well, with the same result.

I append the locator to my settings window using jQuery:

```
settings.append($('<input style="display:none;" id="fileDialog" nwdirectory type="file"/>'));
settings.append($('<span class="saveLoc">'+ options['savelocation'] +'</span>'));
```

and I bind it using the function from the documentation:

```
function chooseFile(name) {
  var chooser = $(name);
  chooser.change(function(evt) {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
  chooser.trigger('click');
}
settings.find('.saveLoc').click(function(){
  chooseFile('#fileDialog');
});
```

The code works if I remove the nwdirectory flag, but then the user can only select files, not folders.

Am I making a mistake? And if not, is there any way for me to extract information about the cause of the crash?

Thanks!

Comment: I found this crash dump article 
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Crash-dump
but it is not generated in the temp folder by default, nor if I specify a folder.

Comment: Same thing happens when I create a new node-webkit program with an index.html which just contains a file dialog input with the nwdirectory flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I was using nw version 0.12.0. When I downgraded to 0.11.6 it works.